# Intermediate Value Theorem. Why $x=s+/2$

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I've read the Intermediate Value Theorem's proof and I understand everything except one line which i've been speculating how it is derived. I know this may be a silly question but it does confuse me. So I will write down the proof from the book and say which line I don't understand:

IVT:

Let $f : [a, b] → \mathbb R$ be continuous and suppose that $u$ lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then there is
a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ where $f(c) = u$.

PROOF: Assume that $f(a) < u < f(b)$ and let $A$ be the set
$\{x \in [a, b] : f(x) \leq u\}$.

This set is non-empty since it contains $a$ and is bounded above by $b$.
Let $s$ be its least upper bound.
The aim is to show that $f(s) = u$.

Suppose that we have $f(s) < u$.

Note that that $s \neq b$ because we know $f(b) > u$.

If we put $E = u − f(s)$
then for some $δ > 0$
$|f(x) − f(s)| < E$
as long as $|x − s| < δ$.

So in particular if $x = s + δ/2$ then $f(x) < f(s) + E = u$.
(**HERE**: I do not understand completely why $x=s+/2$. Is it because it satisfies the condition of $>0$ for when we substitute it in the equation 
$|x-s|< $??)

This means that $s + δ/2 \in A$ contradicting the fact that $s$ is an upper
bound for $A$.

I know the proof continues but I understand the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We want to show that $s+\delta/2\in A$, or equivalently $f(x)\le u$ when $x=s+\delta/2$. So we check that $x=s+\delta/2$ satisfies $|x-s|<\delta$, and thus $|f(x)-f(s)|<E$, which implies $f(x)\le E+f(s)=u$.

Comment: x=s+/2  implies that |s+/2-s|< => /2< => -<0 => >0. Is that what's we want? And is that the goal of setting x=s+/2. All the other things are clear for me

Comment: @ThePoorJew Your implication is not in the right way. We start from $\delta>0$ and $x=s+\delta/2$, then $|x-s|=\delta/2<\delta$. The goal is just to find such an $x$ with the desired property: $x>s$ and $x\in A$. You can also choose $x=s+\delta/10$ or anything like that.